Getting the "You cannot access the NavBackStackEntry's ViewModels after the NavBackStackEntry is destroyed" error when doing "setApplicationLocales()"
So I've been developing the app with Jetpack Compose using Compose Navigation for, well, navigating (here is my NavHose setup in the MainActivity class):
NavHost(
                navController = hiltViewModel<AppViewModel>().controller,
                startDestination = LogInRoute
            ) {
                composable<LogInRoute> {
                    LoginScreen(
                    )
                }
            }

And I've been trying to implement per-app localization with the internal locale picker and everything. I've set it up just like they did in the example app (https://github.com/android/user-interface-samples/tree/main/PerAppLanguages).
I have the button which is supposed to change the locale by clicking it:
// ...
onClick = {
                        AppCompatDelegate.setApplicationLocales(
                            LocaleListCompat.forLanguageTags(
                                "no"
                            )
                        )
                    },
// ...

When I press the button my app closes and shows the error in the terminal:
Error was captured in composition while live edit was enabled.
                                                                                                    java.lang.IllegalStateException: You cannot access the NavBackStackEntry's ViewModels after the NavBackStackEntry is destroyed.
                                                                                                        at androidx.navigation.NavBackStackEntry.getViewModelStore(NavBackStackEntry.kt:207)
                                                                                                        at androidx.lifecycle.viewmodel.compose.ViewModelKt__ViewModelKt.get(ViewModel.kt:155)

...

I've found reports of this error occuring in different situations, but couldn't find a fix for it yet(

Note that you cannot put a NavController in a ViewModel. Do you get the same error when you use rememberNavController directly?

@ianhanniballake Yeah, I think that was the problem. I've replaced the controller form viewModel with the rememberNavController, and the locales change in the proper manner!
But now there is the question of sharing said controleler with my screens ...
